# How to add mnemonics to the commands in sublime on Linux

Tags: sublimetext3

Use keyboard accessible navigation in the sublime context menu

I open a context menu with application-key (near the right alt key) in sublime,
previously I could choose the provided options (in the context menu) with some highlighted letters (often the first letter), but it is not working the same, now.
I must select the option with the arrow & Enter key.

Is there anything I might break?

Sublime v3.2.2 build 3211
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: Does pressing a character key do nothing when the menu is open? For example, in the standard context menu, pressing `C` should jump you back and forth between the Cut and Copy commads; does that work?

Comment: Nothing work when the menu is open, event `prt sc` key is not working, just up/down the array and enter key is working

Comment: The word you are looking for is *mnemonics* — the shortcut key shown on a menu entry and used to select that item. I don't remember having mnemonics available in the Sublime Text context menu but I almost never use it. There are no mnemonics shown by default in the ST version I'm using (build 3176). @OdatNurd seems to have them which is odd because I don't see any mnemonics shown in the default `Context.sublime-menu` file for versions 3211, 3200, and 3176.

Comment: @Amirhossein If you like I will write an answer showing you how to override the default `Context.sublime-menu` file and add the mnemonics you want to use manually. This would give you control over which letters are used for which action. Note that doing this would be fairly advanced software configuration.

Comment: @mattst indeed the context menu files don't have mnemonics in them; what I'm seeing here is not true mnemonics because pressing a character doesn't actually execute the command, it just moves the menu between items that start with that character. Possibly that's some sort of OS specific behaviour; I only checked on one system.

Comment: @OdatNurd I see — you guessed correctly that is OS specific behaviour. It does NOT happen on Linux but does on Windows (I just checked on my Linux Desktop and on a Windows 7 Virtual Machine). Actually I shouldn't say it doesn't happen on Linux, it will depend on which window manager is being used and how that handles context menus, however I suspect the behaviour you've described happens on Windows OSes only.

Comment: thank you @mattst @odaNurd,
It seems `Context.sublime-menu` wont fix it.
Maybe we could add an issue for sublime guys? what do you suggest?

Comment: @Amirhossein You have misunderstood us. You can add mnemonics to the commands in `Context.sublime-menu` by overriding that file with (on Linux) `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Default/Context.sublime-menu`. If you change your question to ask how to do that then I will answer with an explanation.

Comment: @mattst, sorry for being late, I changed the question title, please post how to   override configuration